# FK on table may cause multiple cycles or multple cascade paths

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm creating a database that looks like this: I have `Questions` table:

```
public class Question
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
    public List<SendedAnswer> SendedAnswers { get; set; }
}
```

Someone can send `SendedAnswer` to each question:

```
public class SendedAnswer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionId{ get; set; }

    public Question Question { get; set; }

    public List<ExecutionResult> ExecutionResults { get; set; }
}
```

While answer is sent, my system checks if answers is related to output

`ExecutionResult` stores `ID` to `SendedAnswer` and `Answer` (I added `AnswerId` and error that I show below shows in output from `update-database` after added new migration with this ID). In my code behind, I am checking `SendedAnswer` with `Answers` related to `Question` (`SendedAnswer` is sent to resolve one `Question`).

```
public class ExecutionResult
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SendedAnswer")]
    public int SendedAnswerId { get; set; }

    public SendedAnswer SendedAnswer { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Answer")]
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }

    public Answer Answer { get; set; }
}
```

`Answers` table looks like this:

```
public class Answer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Question")]
    public int QuestionId{ get; set; }

    public Question Question{ get; set; }
}
```

After adding migration with new column for storing `AnswerId` in `ExecutionResult` class, I get this error:

> Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.ExecutionResults_dbo.Answers_AnswerId' on table 'ExecutionResults' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
>   Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.

When I added this line to my `DbContext` (in overridden method):

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

I get errors, that my `IdentityUsers` is lack of couple of `IDs` etc (my DbContext inheritace from `IdentityDbContext<User>`).

My question is, how to deal with this error? When I get multiple cascade on delete paths? For me it looking ok because after deleting `Answer` I want to delete `ExecutionResult` and it looks pretty obvious that I need FK in `ExecutionResult` to `Answer` and `SendedAnswer`.

How to match `Answers` table with `ExecutionResult` table without that error? What did I do wrong here?

Comment: Actually you no need excutionResult table, put user answer into SendAnswer Table, or if you want put more detail information in ExecutionResult table, then you should remove AnswerID from ExecutionResult table, based on SendAnswerId you can get AnswerID.

Comment: I need execution table. SendedAnswer store `Code`, ExecutionResult store `Output` from this code. i need another table to store that output and checking it with answers to related question

Comment: If we have 4  Answers in `Question`, i need 4 ExecutionResult because ExecutionResult triggers for each Answer (4 answers, 4 rsults)

Comment: When you send an answer, then it is **sent** (not "sended") ....

Comment: @michasaucer Check my answer! It will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Add `[Required]` Attribute on your foreign key constraints to force cascade deleting.
Alternatively use the entity framework fluent api to define some other OnDelete Behaviour depending on your needs. (https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();` from `OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)` and add the following **Fluent API** configuration as follows:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
      base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ExecutionResult>().HasRequired(er => er.SendedAnswer)
            .WithMany(sa => sa.ExecutionResults).HasForeignKey(er => er.SendedAnswerId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

      modelBuilder.Entity<ExecutionResult>().HasRequired(er => er.Answer)
            .WithMany().HasForeignKey(er => er.AnswerId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
}
```

Now generate the migration again and update the database.